# R: Create New Variable Using Values From Another Variable

Tags: r, variables

I am working with a data set and am needing to create a new variable (basic_adj) and populate it with the contents of another variable (employment_adj) while meeting a set of conditions (indcode >= 2400, Indcode < 3100).

The data set:

| indcode | employment_adj | basic_adj |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2401 | 29.2 | 29.2 |
| 3090 | 31.2 | 31.2 |
| 5200 | 12.4 |  |

I have attempted to do this with the following code, but am not getting the desired result which is to populate the new third column (basic_adj) with the contents of the second column (employment_adj) as long as it meets a specific criteria from the first column (indcode):

```
indcode <- c(2401, 3090, 5200)
employment_adj <- c(29.2,31.2,12.4)   
df <- data.frame(indcode, employment_adj)
df$basic_adj <- factor (ifelse(df$indcode >= 2400 & df$indcode < 3100, "1", NA))
```

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: `ifelse` always must have three arguments, you are missing its `yes=` and `no=` arguments. Your code also doesn't close out the call to `factor`. It's difficult troubleshooting code that won't even pass the initial parser, please test (and fix) all of your code.

Comment: *"am not getting the desired result"* ... how? What are you getting, and what do you expect? Saying it isn't working but not including the current and expected behavior is a little frustrating in that you are requiring that we all run your code to be able to even begin to see what the error/warning or mistake is. This is (of course) exacerbated by having incomplete/non-functional code.

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `factor(.)` on `numeric` data, it is almost always not appropriate there.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am new to this and there is clearly still lots to learn. I have updated my code and provided more detail to my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this in base R. The 2 issues with your attempt are that (a), the `ifelse` function takes 3 arguments - you need to specify what the function should return if the statement is true and false. (b) you need to somehow loop over each element of the incode vector.

For example, using `transform`:

```
indcode <- c(2401, 3090, 5200)
employment_adj <- c(29.2,31.2,12.4)   
df <- data.frame(indcode, employment_adj)

df <- transform(df, basic_adj = ifelse(indcode >= 2400 & indcode < 3100, 1, 0))
```

Or you could "loop through" each element of the vector using `sapply`

```
df$basic_adj = sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) ifelse(df$indcode[i] >= 2400 & df$indcode[i] < 3100, 1, 0))
```

Most R users doing a lot of these types of transformations using either the `dplyr` or `data.table` packages to make working with dataframes faster/easier. Here is how you could do it in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

indcode <- c(2401, 3090, 5200)
employment_adj <- c(29.2,31.2,12.4)   
df <- data.frame(indcode, employment_adj)
dat <- as.data.table(df)
 
dat[, basic_adj := ifelse(indcode >= 2400 & indcode < 3100, 1, 0)]


> dat
   indcode employment_adj basic_adj
1:    2401           29.2         1
2:    3090           31.2         1
3:    5200           12.4         0
```

It is worth investing time in learning one of these packages if you are doing a lot of data munging.